# Why does .children.length only return 2?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the number of child elements of `wrapper` by using the `.length` property, but when using it with `.children` the count is always equal to 2.

```
    <div id="wrapper">
       <div>content a</div> <!-- visible -->
       <div>content b</div> <!-- visible -->
       <div>content c</div> <!-- not visible -->
       <div>content d</div> <!-- not visible -->
    </div>
```

As I have learnt on SO the length property does not take element visibility into account. Therefore,  in this case the returned value should equal **4**, but when using `$('#wrapper').children.length;` only **2** is returned.

**Question: Why is `$('#wrapper').children.length;` only returning 2?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check

```
$('#train').children().length
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7sjfY/)

You are getting 2 because 
`$('#train').children.length` return the `number of arguments expected by the function.`

For details see [Function.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)

In your case `$('#train').children` references to a function which is expecting 2 arguments that is why you are getting 2 as the output, not because it is the number if visible children

Comment: Thank you Johny, can't believe it came down to a bracket issue... I guess if I had more than 4 elements at the time it would have been clearer.

Answer (score 3):

> *Forums point to the `.length` property, but this only returns the amount of visible items.*

No, `.length` returns the number of elements in the jQuery object in question, regardless of how you got the jQuery object or whether the elements are currently visible.

> *How do I count all of the children of #train?*

Well you can do whichever of these makes sense for your situation:

```
// all direct children of any element type
$("#train").children().length
// OR just the DIV children
$("#train").children("div").length
// OR all descendant DIVs
$("#train").find("div").length
```

> *when using `$('#train').children.length;` 2 is returned.*

That's because you didn't actually call the `.children()` method - you left off the parentheses, which means you got the `.length` property of the function itself, which returns the number of declared arguments.

Answer (score 3):

You problem is that you forgot the parenthesis.

As surprising as it might be, this returns 2, whatever the element :

```
$(element).children.length
```

Add the parenthesis and it's OK :

```
$(element).children().length
```

Why did you get 2 ? That's because the length of a function is, [as said by the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length),

> the number of arguments expected by the function.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#train > div:visible').length  //visible ones
$('#train > div:hidden').length //hidden ones
$('#train > div').length //all children DIVs
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var childrenCount = $('#train').children().length;
```

Comment: Maybe it will (i haven't tested) but maybe you can explain why this will work and why the OP's code doesn't work. That's what I meant.

Comment: according to the OP markup `children()` will return all 4 `div`, that are inside of `div` with `id="train"`

Comment: OP didn't trigger the `children` method, he got the value of the `children` property (which is a function actually)

Answer (score 1):

This would do it

```
$('#train').children().length
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the below code:

```
$('#train').children.length;
```

Use the below code:

```
$('#train').children("div").length;
```